# PatternSyntaxException in Java (matching Windows registry path)

Tags: java, regex

I got a method that looks like the following, and when I try to run it, I got an exception.

*java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 6
^HKLM\*

Anyone able to spot what's wrong with my regular expression?  What I am trying to do is to check against a string which is a Windows registry path and ensure that it is supported by my software.

```
    final String SUPPRTED_REGISTRY_PATH_REGEX[] = new String[] {
        "^HKLM\\",
        "^HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\",
        "^HKCR\\",
        "^HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\"
    };

    boolean isValidated = false;

    // Windows registry path is case-insensitive therefore
    // convert the registry path to all upper case for
    // ease of comparison
    String uppercaseRegistryPath = registryPath.toUpperCase(); 

    for(int i = 0;
        i < SUPPRTED_REGISTRY_PATH_REGEX.length && isValidated == false;
        i++) {

        if(Pattern.matches(
                SUPPRTED_REGISTRY_PATH_REGEX[i], uppercaseRegistryPath)) {
            isValidated = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A backslash character is represented by a `\\` character. To represent this in regex requires that each character be escaped, producing `\\\\`.

```
String SUPPRTED_REGISTRY_PATH_REGEX[] = new String[] {
   "^HKLM\\\\",
   "^HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\\\",
   "^HKCR\\\\",
   "^HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\\\"
}
```

- [Pattern docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: Yup, it's working now!  Thanks

But I thought I escaped my backslash already.  The first \ is the search pattern and the 2nd \ is the escape character.  What is the two extra backslashes are for?

Answer (score 4):

Normally to represent `\` literal in regex you need to escape it once `\\`.

But in Java you also need to escape special meaning of `\` in String. So you will have to use `"\\\\"` to produce `\\` literal that will be used in regex to match `\` literal.

Simple isn't it :)